# Using multiple AudioUnits with MTAudioProcessingTap on iOS

Tags: ios, audiounit

I'm attempting to play audio files from the users' iPod library on an iOS device, while using AudioUnit to apply a parametric EQ effect. I have been using this sample as a guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor/Introduction/Intro.html

I have the EQ effect working, but I need to add multiple EQ effects.

In my 'process' callback, I tried running AudioUnitRender multiple times, on multiple AudioUnit effects (all of type Parametric EQ).

```
status = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit, 0, &audioTimeStamp, 0, (UInt32)numberFrames, bufferListInOut);
```

With any more than 1 AudioUnitRender call, the audio skips and cuts out.

How can I use multiple Parametric EQ effects at once?

Thanks

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem? Struggling with the same...

Answer (score 3):

I'm still not sure what the reason of the glitch is, but I've found the solution and it's probably what AUGraph does internally.

The trick is to call `AudioUnitRender()` of the next AU from within the render callback function of the previous AU. The last render callback calls `MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio()`. Assuming you have a single render callback for all your AU's and assuming you have an array with all the AU's you created:

```
UInt64 processedFrames;
UInt32 curAudioUnit;
UInt32 audioUnitCount;
AudioUnit audioUnits[MAX_AUDIO_UNITS];

OSStatus AU_RenderCallback(void *tap, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, UInt32 inBusNumber, UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
    curAudioUnit++;
    if (curAudioUnit == audioUnitCount)
        return MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, inNumberFrames, ioData, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    AudioTimeStamp audioTimeStamp;
    audioTimeStamp.mSampleTime = processedFrames;
    audioTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
    return AudioUnitRender(audioUnits[curAudioUnit], 0, &audioTimeStamp, 0, inNumberFrames, ioData);
}


void tap_ProcessCallback(MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap, CMItemCount inNumberFrames, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags flags, AudioBufferList *bufferListInOut, CMItemCount *numberFramesOut, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags *flagsOut)
{
    if (audioUnitCount)
    {
        curAudioUnit = 0;
        AudioTimeStamp audioTimeStamp;
        audioTimeStamp.mSampleTime = processedFrames;
        audioTimeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
        AudioUnitRender(audioUnits[curAudioUnit], 0, &audioTimeStamp, 0, inNumberFrames, bufferListInOut);
    }
    else
        MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, inNumberFrames, bufferListInOut, flagsOut, NULL, numberFramesOut);

    processedFrames += inNumberFrames;
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to avoid calling MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio in the renderCallback? Why can't it be called before calling AudioUnitRender()?